# Let $\{s_n\}$ , $\{t_n\}$ with $s_n<c<t_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\{t_n-s_n\}=0$, prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{f(t_n)-f(s_n)}{t_n-s_n}=f'(c).$

Tags: real-analysis

This question is from Manfred Stoll: Introduction to Real Analysis 3ed. Miscellaneous Exercises #6, Chapter 5, pg. 221.

> 6. Suppose $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c \in (a,b)$. If $\{s_n\}$ and $\{t_n\}$ are sequences in $(a,b)$ with $s_n <c<t_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\{t_n-s_n\}=0$, prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{f(t_n)-f(s_n)}{t_n-s_n}=f'(c).$$

To reduce notational clutter I have assumed that $c=0$, $f(c)=0$ and $f'(c)=L$. Thus we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}{s_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{t_n}=c=0$. By appropriate choices of $\delta$ and application of the triangle inequality it is readily seen that $$\Bigg |\dfrac{f(s_n)}{s_n}-L+\dfrac{f(t_n)}{t_n}-L\Bigg |<\epsilon.$$

We can then rewrite the expression inside the absolute value by giving the terms a common denominator of $s_n t_n(t_n-s_n)$. This yields $$\Bigg | \dfrac{t_n^2f(s_n)-s_nt_nf(s_n)+s_nt_nf(t_n)-s_n^2f(t_n)}{s_nt_n(t_n-s_n)}-2L\Bigg |$$ Now this can be decomposed into the function we are looking at and a second term as follows: $$\Bigg | \dfrac{f(t_n)-f(s_n)}{t_n-s_n}-L+\dfrac{t_n\left[\dfrac{f(s_n)}{s_n}-L\right]-s_n\left[\dfrac{f(t_n)}{t_n}-L\right]}{t_n-s_n}\Bigg|$$

This is where I am stuck.  Its tempting to just toss in two multiples of $\epsilon$ into the second term thus allowing the cancelation of the pesky $t_n-s_n$ terms but that doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Note that $$\Bigg|\dfrac{f(t_n)-f(s_n)}{t_n-s_n}-L\Bigg|=\Bigg |\dfrac{f(s_n)}{s_n}-L+\dfrac{f(t_n)}{t_n}-L\ -\Bigg(\dfrac{t_n\left[\dfrac{f(s_n)}{s_n}-L\right]-s_n\left[\dfrac{f(t_n)}{t_n}-L\right]}{t_n-s_n}    \Bigg) \Bigg |  \leq \Bigg|\dfrac{f(s_n)}{s_n}-L\Bigg|+\Bigg|\dfrac{f(t_n)}{t_n}-L \Bigg|+ \Bigg| \dfrac{t_n\left[\dfrac{f(s_n)}{s_n}-L\right]}{t_n-s_n}  \Bigg|+\Bigg| \dfrac{s_n\left[\dfrac{f(t_n)}{t_n}-L\right]}{t_n-s_n}\Bigg|\leq2\Bigg|\dfrac{f(s_n)}{s_n}-L\Bigg|+2\Bigg|\dfrac{f(t_n)}{t_n}-L \Bigg|.$$
The last inequality is the crux of the solution and comes from the fact that $0<-s_n<t_n-s_n$ and $0<t_n<t_n-s_n$ which allows us to use $\Bigg|\dfrac{t_n}{t_n-s_n}\Bigg|<1$ and $\Bigg|\dfrac{s_n}{t_n-s_n}\Bigg|<1$ in the last inequality. Thus we have $$\Bigg|\dfrac{f(t_n)-f(s_n)}{t_n-s_n}-L\Bigg|\leq 2\Bigg|\dfrac{f(s_n)}{s_n}-L\Bigg|+2\Bigg|\dfrac{f(t_n)}{t_n}-L \Bigg|.$$ Therefore choose $N$ such that each of the two right hand expressions within the absolute values in less than $\epsilon/4$ for all $n\geq N$ and the proposition is proved.

Many thanks to @ViníciusNovelli for the idea that completed the proof.

Comment: nice question and answer +2